# I want to make sure the basement bathroom is plumbed correctly

Tags: plumbing, basement

Going to tap into the sewer line in the basement for a new 3/4 bathroom. Can I run a 4" branch to the toilet and have two 2" wye connections for the shower and vanity? Below shows the sewer location.

[image: Concept of the new bathroom layout]

This image shows the new branch, 4" to toilet with wyes. Green is vents. I might do studors?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good diagrams, but what slope will these pipes have? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! The slope will be 0.25" per foot. I was reading other DIY questions here and I think I have a good idea of what is necessary. I will update the question with an isometric drawing to show things a bit better. It will help me when I get a permit too.